# Is there a standard notation for 'written in base a'?

Tags: notation, soft-question

I am considering a procedure in which it is useful to switch between bases and operate on a number in these different bases (take decimal truncations etc). What matters here is the actual sequnce of digits. Now at the end of an operation, I have a sequnce of digits corresponding to a number in base 3 say, and I wish now to express the sequence which is "the number corresponding to the sequnce written in base 3, now written in base 10". Is there a nice notation for this that I am not aware of?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I'd call it standard, but it's at least common to write something like "$2\text{A}_{16} = 1120_{3} = 42_{10}$" (though it would be nice to describe this notation when it's introduced). In this case, you'd therefore have (If I'm understanding the function you have in mind) something along the lines of, "Write $n = (a_0 \cdots a_n)_{3}$, and put $f(n) = (a_0 \cdots a_n)_{10}$.

Comment: Personally, I wonder if it depends on the target audience.  I would overkill it with something like $$1201_{[\text{base }~3]}$$

Comment: The subscript notation seems to be common in papers prepared using mathematical typesetting like TeX.  Many programming languages have tried to solve this without typesetting: standard decimal ints without special indication, leading 0 for octal, leading Ox or suffix H for hex.  Ada used notation base#value, eg 16#deadbeef#, 3#01001, 3#012102

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's common to write
$$
13 = 111_3 .
$$
With no subscript, the convention is that you have written the base $10$ expansion of the number.

You can safely use that notation, Just explain it to your reader the first time.

The base (the subscript) is written in base 10, so
$$
A_{16} = 10
$$
and
$$
10_n = n .
$$